# Does Zsh have an equivalent to Bash's "local +x MY_VAR"?

Tags: zsh

In Bash, the following function passes the exported ENV variable to the child process, while also declaring a local variable w/the same name. Is there an equivalent in Zsh?

I don't want to use `subshells` and `read-only variables`. The goal is to avoid accidentally overriding a variable the child process uses.  I won't know which ENV variables are used in the child process or which are pre-existing from the calling process.

In Zsh, `local +x`, has different behaviour than the one in Bash. Zsh seems to unset the variable using `local` or `local +x`. (`+x` in `local +x` is ignored  in Zsh.) Bash passes on the original variable using `local +x`:

```
function the_func {
  local +x  MY_VAR="new value"
  my -child -process  # === in zsh:  $MY_VAR is undefined
                      # === in bash: $MY_VAR="original"
}

export MY_VAR="original"
the_func
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such equivalent in ZSH.